# How do you handle adding nullable columns to each other in a query?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Currently whenever I write a query that is adding columns that can contain nulls I resort to wrapping each field in `isnull` or `coalesce`, such as `coalesce(score1,0) + coalesce(score2,0)`.
Is there a better way to handle this, or is this the standard practice?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are these insert / update statements? Are you adding a nullable column to a table, and want a default for existing records or new records?

Comment: @Eric Humphrey: Edited the question for clarity. The question was meant for querying columns that can contain nulls, and wanting to add some of them together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's pretty much what you have to do. Since NULL + anything else is NULL, you have to wrap each column in its own isnull(), coalesce() or CASE.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle provides [NVL()](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php) for this scenario, [ISNULL()](http://cf-bill.blogspot.com/2005/10/oracle-nvl-microsoft-isnull.html) is the equivalent in MS SQL Server. You could disguise all this in a VIEW to make your code clearer.